# call batch script exiting with error 0 even with exit /b number

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script start.bat

```
@echo off
SET Cp=0
if "%Cp%" EQU "0" (
CALL "Disclaimer.bat"
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 102 (
contiue code here
) else (
goto :eof
)
)
```

the Disclaimer.bat has text and an except or not

```
:dsr
SET /P dsrc=Do you accept the disclaimer (Y)es (N)o [Y/N]?
if /I "%dsrc%" EQU "Y" exit /B 102
if /I "%dsrc%" EQU "N" goto :eof
goto dsr
```

the return from the Disclaimer.bat is error 0 even though exit is 102

Comment: Type `set /?` and read about delayed expansion. Test the normal way and it will work - `if errorlevel 182 if not errorlevel 183 Command`

Comment: Multi-line code blocks are too-often problematic.  Avoid them.  How do you know Disclaimer.bat is returning zero?

Comment: Why check whether `Cp` is zero? You just set it to zero immediately prior to the if statement.

Comment: ok got it using !

Comment: the Cp is conditional to earlier code and only given here to show that it is set as the earlier code works. I had echoed out the return of Disclaimer.bat which was 0 due to not using !!

Comment: So where is your problem then?  If it's in Disclaimer.bat, why post the other script?  You really need to read [Ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: I updated my answer to include checking `%Cp%`.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to your start.bat script, except it doesn't have any problems with the relative timing of variable expansions:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@rem @set prompt=$G

@if "%Cp%" neq "0" exit /b 0
@call "Disclaimer.bat"
@if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 102 @exit /b 0
contiue code here
```

Note that the above code does not use any parens to group code lines together and thus avoids the need for delayed expansion. Script writers spend more time tracking down problems in multi-line code blocks than anywhere else in their code. It's hard to debug, even with delayed expansion. You are better off adopting a more organized style of coding that avoids multi-line code blocks.

I tested your Disclaimer.bat script and got the following the results:

```
> test
Do you accept the disclaimer (Y)es (N)o [Y/N]?Y

>if /I "Y" EQU "Y" exit /B 102

14:44:47.74
D:\TMP\Joseph

> echo %errorlevel%
102

14:45:08.96
D:\TMP\Joseph

> test
Do you accept the disclaimer (Y)es (N)o [Y/N]?N

>if /I "N" EQU "Y" exit /B 102

>if /I "N" EQU "N" goto :eof

14:45:21.87
D:\TMP\Joseph

> echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Obviously, your assumption regarding the behavior of Disclaimer.bat is incorrect. It does return 102 when the user enters `Y` and it returns zero when the user enters `N` at the prompt.

Comment: I used echo for error in the start.bat as the return path from the CALL which gave 0 whether Disclaimer.bat was answered Y or N I resolved the issue using SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion and !! instead of %% in start.bat which is calling Disclaimer.bat. I had previously tried with SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion in start.bat however I had it in the wrong place therefore it did nothing